# Difference in address of variable when printing in main and in a function

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printaddr(int n)
{
    printf("%p", &n);
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("%p \n", &n);
    printaddr(n);
}
```

Address of variable n in main loop is printed : 0028FF0C , while in function printaddr its printed 0028FEF0 .

I want to know why is there difference in address and whether or not does that difference represent anything ?

Comment: That was because I was using my standard C ++ template which got changed completely while translating code to C. I'm aware that using namespace std; is not C syntax, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 5):

The addresses are different because they are two different variables.

When you call a function, the function parameters are initialized with copies of the function argument values.  If you changed `n` inside `printaddr`, it would have no effect on the value of `n` inside `main`.

Answer (score 2):

Because in

```
void printaddr(int n)
```

you are creating a new local variable `n` ( local to the function ) with a different address.

You could instead use a pointer like

```
void printaddr(int *n)
```

and call it as

```
printaddr(&n);
```

So, if you change your code to

```
#include<stdio.h>
void printaddr(int *n)
{
    printf("%p", n);
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("%p \n", &n);
    printaddr(&n);
}
```

You will get the same address. ( But please note that the `n` inside the function would just point to the address of the `n` from `main()` , it does not have the same address as it )

Answer (score 2):

The function gets a copy of the variable, because of pass-by-value semantics.  So, it's actually a different variable.  The addresses are different because the memory is different.

As a test, try changing `n` in `printaddr` and seeing if it changes in `main`.  Hint, it won't.

You can pass a pointer to a function if you want to have access to the same chunk of memory.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what Arun A.S has mentioned:

You are calling the function:

```
void printaddr(int n)
```

and you caller is passing in `n` (by value) rather than `&n` (the address of n), so you are passing by value rather than reference.

When you pass by value the value is locally copied to the function, so the original value is not changed.

Once the function completes, the local copy of n is destroyed unless you return the value.

This is why if you change the value of `n` in that same function (without returning the value) it will not be the same value when you access the variable `n` from your main.

Comment: The post is tagged [c], which does not have "pass by reference".

Comment: There is no pass by reference in c, even when you pass the address of a variable you do so by value.

Comment: Thanks guys, I actually can learn something when I thought I was the teacher :)

Comment: @aschepler I did note that and commented to the other answer, but look at the top of the source, or read my comment to the question.